# Change the status of the RecycleView item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have request tabs in which "RECEIVED" retrieves data from BD Firebase within a RecycleView. This request is made by a user and received by the company. Now how do I do the following:

1 - The company representative clicks on an item of the incoming request to appear an AlertDialog whether or not to respond to the request.

2 - If you answer, delete the item "RECEIVED" and appear in "ATTENDED". If not, appear in "PENDING".

If possible notify the user also about these actions.  Thanks to whoever helps.

Code:

```
    public class SolicRecebidaFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerViewListaSolicitacao;
private DatabaseReference refSolicitacao, database ;
private AdapterSolicitacoes adapter;
private ArrayList<DadosSolicitacao> listaSolicitacoes = new ArrayList<>();
private ValueEventListener valueEventoSolicitacao;
private String idUsuario;


public SolicRecebidaFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_solicitacao_recebida, container, false);

    //Config.Inciais
    recyclerViewListaSolicitacao = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_ListaSolicitacao);

    //Config.Referenciar nó de recuperação dos dados
   // idUsuario = IdUsuarioFirabase.getIdentificadorUsuario();
    database = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseDataBase();
    refSolicitacao = database
            .child("solicitacao_coleta");

    //Config.Adapter
    adapter = new AdapterSolicitacoes(listaSolicitacoes, getActivity());

    //Config.RecyclerView
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerViewListaSolicitacao.setLayoutManager( layoutManager);
    recyclerViewListaSolicitacao.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewListaSolicitacao.addItemDecoration( new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), LinearLayout.VERTICAL));
    recyclerViewListaSolicitacao.setAdapter( adapter );

    //Evento de click
    recyclerViewListaSolicitacao.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), recyclerViewListaSolicitacao,
                    new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item clicado",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item pressionado",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                        }
                    })
    );

return view;
}

@Override //Exibi lista ao carregar o fragment
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    recuperarSolicitacao();
}

@Override // Remove lista ao sair do fragment
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    refSolicitacao.removeEventListener(valueEventoSolicitacao);
}

public void recuperarSolicitacao (){

   valueEventoSolicitacao =  refSolicitacao.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            listaSolicitacoes.clear();

            for ( DataSnapshot dados: dataSnapshot.getChildren() ){

               // Log.i("DADOS COLETA FIREBASE", dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());

                DadosSolicitacao solicitacao = dados.getValue(DadosSolicitacao.class);
                listaSolicitacoes.add( solicitacao );

            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}

    }
```

Comment: yes possible use custom click listener for adapter. your firebase listener will trigger automatically when data are updated. so your `onDataChange`at will call . you can handle there

Comment: So I would have to make a listener in the request fragment attende, to capture the click changes of the request fragment received?

Comment: yes and your firebase listener also will trigger when data are changed in firebase